# PopUp View in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wanna to create a popView model in MVC3 :

this is my actionlink :

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Category", new { categoryId = Item.Id }, null)
```

and also this the related actionresult!

```
 public ActionResult Edit(Guid categoryId)
        {
            var category = _categoryService.GetCategory(categoryId);
            return View(category);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _categoryService.UpdateCategory(categoryViewModel.Id);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

I wanna to open this page (actionlike in a popUp), how can I do that ???thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sample maybe useful:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css") rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
```

Now lets dig in to the jQuery code required for the modal popup to work.

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .attr("id", $(this)
        .attr("data-dialog-id"))
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
        close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
        modal: true,
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        left: 0

    })
    .load(this.href);
    });

    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
</script>
```

In the ActionLink defined below we are using the following 3 properties,

- `class` – indicates that on click of this link, execute the jQuery written above
- `data_dialog_id`
- `data_dialog_title` – used to display the title of the jQuery modal popup

Razor code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Open Jquery Modal Popup", "About", "Home",null,new {
@class = "openDialog",
data_dialog_id = "aboutDialog",
data_dialog_title = "About Us"
})
```

Below is the "About" action of the "Home" controller which will be called when a user clicks on the above ActionLink.

Controller

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

Below is the About.cshtml view which will be display by the above (About) action. Note that I have set the layout to null, so that I don't get duplicate master template showing up on each other.

`About.cshtml` view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
    Layout = null;
}


<h2>About</h2>
<p>
Hello, this is a modal jquery popup !
</p>
<p><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close">Close this Window</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your actionlink to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Category", new { categoryId = Item.Id }, new { target="_blank" })
```